# Matplotlib throws AttributeError: get_content_extents when plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use matplotlib in my python script in order to display some graphs. But everytime I call it, I get the error

```
AttributeError: get_content_extents
```

MWE:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> def a(x):
...     return x*x
... 
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d = np.linspace(0, 10, 2**12)
>>> plt.plot(d, a(d))
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f1edc44d350>]
>>> plt.show()
```

Result is:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 176, in __draw_idle_agg
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 469, in draw
    self.renderer = self.get_renderer(cleared=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 486, in get_renderer
    self.renderer = RendererAgg(w, h, self.figure.dpi)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 99, in __init__
    self._update_methods()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 134, in _update_methods
    self.get_content_extents = self._renderer.get_content_extents
AttributeError: get_content_extents
```

The same happens if I try to change the backend with

```
plt.switch_backend('qt4agg')
```

When trying the `gtk` backend ('gtkagg'), I get

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:127: RuntimeWarning: PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK
  set_interactive(1)
```

What can I do to fix that?

Comment: How did you install matplotlib?  What version are you running?  I suspect there is something wrong with your installation as I can not reproduce this.

Comment: I installed matplotlib 1.5.0, as usual via pip